# How to filter an array (using a regex) in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Firstly I am brand new to C#, this is my first take on coding outside of HTML and CSS. I currently have a very large array and I want to filter said array by checking each string, if the string has a certain letter in it (in this case if it has any of the following letters (gkqmvwxz) then I want to move on from it and keep looking.

Once I find a string in the array that works I want to keep checking for the longest possible one. (This is from Tom Scott's video about 7 Segment Displays, it felt like a good challenge and he did his in javascript)

My Code looks like this

```
namespace Longest_Word_in_a_7_segment_display
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string english = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Max\Desktop\words.txt");
            char[] full = english.ToCharArray();



        }
    }
}
```

I have defined the string and converted it into an array, I've looked through regex syntax and tried some solutions but they all seem above me. Whats the best way to start learning how to do this so I can fully understand it?

Comment: You don't seem to have got very far. Were you intending to split the text into 'words'? Or lines? Because what you have so far - `ToCharArray` - [splits the text into individual characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_ToCharArray]). Which won't work for what you want to do.

Comment: If this is really your first coding attempt in any programming language (HTML and CSS don't count) then this is not at all an appropriate project to start with.

Comment: If this problem is too hard you need to [find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). Forget about arrays and “filtering” for now and write code that simply displays the words in your file. Then display something like the first character of each word. Then instead of the first character, display a selected character. Then try determining if a word that has the selected character instead of always displaying it. You probably won't need arrays or regexes at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to start with basics. I am afraid you took big piece of cake to handle it. If you are brand new to C# you are only going to struggle and maybe give up in the future.

If you don't mind to start learning there is [Introduction to C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/) with interactive tutorials or [C# Fundamentals: Development for Absolute Beginners](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners). If I were you I'll start there or find some other tutorials on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

[Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8) works on `string` not on `char[]`,  I'd recommend you do the following

```cs
string english = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Max\Desktop\words.txt");
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b\w*(g|k|q|m|v|w|x|z)\w*\b");
List<string> filteredWords = regex.Matches(english).Select(x=> x.Value).ToList(); ///Using System.Linq
```